# How to get one value (clicked one) from for loop in JS addEventListener Django project

Tags: javascript, html, django

Im trying connect JS inside my Django project I got message in console that

```
HTMLCollection(2) [p.currency-one, p.currency-one]

HTMLCollection(2) [input.amount-one, input.amount-one]
app.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: c1.addEventListener is not a function
   at app.js:21:4
(anonymous) @   app.js:21
```

JS file

```
const c1 = document.getElementsByClassName("currency-one");
const c2 = document.getElementById("currency-two");
const amount1 = document.getElementsByClassName("amount-one");
const amount2 = document.getElementById("amount-two");
const swap = document.getElementById("swap");
const theRate = document.getElementById("rate");

console.log(c1,amount1)

function calculate() {
 const curr1 = c1.innerHTML;
 const curr2 = c2.innerHTML;
 const rate = parseInt(amount1.value) / parseFloat(amount2.innerHTML);    
 theRate.innerText = `You can buy maximum  -> you wallet money ${amount1.value} ${curr1}  = ${rate} ${curr2}`;
}

// THIS PART OF THE CODE does not know how to get two pieces of information from one //class, how to get through it ?

c1.addEventListener("change", calculate);
amount1.addEventListener("input", calculate);
c2.addEventListener("change", calculate);
amount2.addEventListener("input", calculate);


swap.addEventListener("click", () => {
 const flash = c1.value;
 c1.value = c2.value;
 c2.value = flash;
 calculate();
});
```

view.py

```
def a(request,crypto_name, fiat_currency=None):

   buttons = [
           {"currency_type": "USD", "active": "", "display_text": "USD"},
           {"currency_type": "EUR", "active": "", "display_text": "Euro"},
           {"currency_type": "CNY", "active": "", "display_text": "Chinese Yuan"},
           {"currency_type": "JPY", "active": "", "display_text": "Japanese Yen"},
       ]
   for button in buttons:
       if button['currency_type'] == fiat_currency:
           button['active'] = 'active'

   crypto_detail_view = load_detail_crypto(crypto_name,fiat_currency)

   user_purchased_currencies = UserPurchasedCurrencies.objects.filter(user = request.user)
   user_walet_info_amount_and_name = [x for i in user_purchased_currencies for x in (i.currency_amount,i.currency)]
   x = crypto_name
   context = {
           "crypto_detail_view" : crypto_detail_view,
           "buttons" : buttons,
           "crypto_name" : crypto_name,
           "fiat_currency" : fiat_currency,
           "user_walet_info_amount_and_name" : user_walet_info_amount_and_name,
           "user_purchased_currencies" : user_purchased_currencies,

       }
   return render(request, 'web/a.html', context)
```

html

```
{% extends "web/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
   
   <br><br><br>
   <div id="jumbotron" class="jumbotron" style="text-align: center; margin-top:-50px">
     <h1 id="devise" class="display-5">Devise </h1>
     <h5>Exchange Rate Converter</h5>
     <img src="image.jpg" class="image" style="width:100px; margin-bottom:-50px; " >
   </div>
   <div class="container">
   <div class="page-header" id="banner">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-15">
         <h1 style="align-content: center;"> </h1>
         <p class="lead" style="margin-left:280px; font-size:2rem">
       </p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>



   <div class="row">
       {% for item in buttons %}
       {% for money_purchased in user_purchased_currencies %}
       {% if item.currency_type != money_purchased.currency %}

       {% else %}
       <div class="col-4 col-md-4" >
           <p class="currency-one">{{item.display_text}}</p>
       <a   href="{% url 'a' crypto_name=crypto_name fiat_currency=item.currency_type %}" class="btn btn-outline-dark {{item.active}}" role="button"   >{{item.display_text}}</a>    
       </div>
           <input type="number" class="amount-one"  value="{{money_purchased.currency_amount}}" style="width:100%" />
       {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %} 
   </div>


<br>
 <div class="swap-btn">
   <button type="button" id="swap" class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-auto d-block" >Swap <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
 </div>
 
 <div class="rate" id="rate"></div>
   <br>
   {% for crypto in crypto_detail_view %}
   <div class="container">
     <div class="currency">

            <p class="form-control" id="currency-two">{{crypto.name}}</p>
     <br>
     <p class="form-control" type="number" id="amount-two"  style="width:100%">{{crypto.price}}</p>
       
     </div>
 </div>
 {% endfor %} 



 <script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>


 {% endblock %}
```

I would like to get only this two but just those clicked values

```
c1.addEventListener("change", calculate);
amount1.addEventListener("input", calculate);
```

part of the code in views checks what currencies the user has purchased , when the user clicks on USD for example, he will received how much USD he has to use and when he already selected / clicked, then the code in JS should select the appropriate amount and currency name.
How to do it? with the use of loops?

```
   <div class="row">
       {% for item in buttons %}
       {% for money_purchased in user_purchased_currencies %}
       {% if item.currency_type != money_purchased.currency %}

       {% else %}
       <div class="col-4 col-md-4" >
           <p class="currency-one">{{item.display_text}}</p>
       <a   href="{% url 'a' crypto_name=crypto_name fiat_currency=item.currency_type %}" class="btn btn-outline-dark {{item.active}}" role="button"   >{{item.display_text}}</a>    
       </div>
           <input type="number" class="amount-one"  value="{{money_purchased.currency_amount}}" style="width:100%" />
       {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %} 
   </div>
```

Update

Now, no matter what I click the USD or the Japanese Yen I get the last currency from the for loop, how to fix it?

```
let c1 = document.getElementsByClassName("currency-one");
let c2 = document.getElementById("currency-two");
let amount1 = document.getElementsByClassName("amount-one");
const amount2 = document.getElementById("amount-two");
const swap = document.getElementById("swap");
const theRate = document.getElementById("rate");



function calculate(curr1,amount11) {
  //let curr1 = c1.innerHTML;
  console.log("C1", curr1, i)
  const curr2 = c2.innerHTML;
  const rate = amount11 / parseFloat(amount2.innerHTML);    
  theRate.innerText = `You can buy maximum  -> you wallet money ${amount11} ${curr1}  = ${rate} ${curr2}`;
}

for(var i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
    console.log("dsada",c1[i].innerHTML,amount1[i].value)
    let curr1 = c1[i].innerHTML;
    let amount11 = parseInt(amount1[i].value) ;
    c1[i].addEventListener("change", calculate(curr1,amount11));
    amount1[i].addEventListener("input", calculate(curr1,amount11));
    }

  c2.addEventListener("change", calculate);
  amount2.addEventListener("input", calculate);


swap.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const flash = c1.value;
  c1.value = c2.value;
  c2.value = flash;
  calculate();
});
```

one variable should be outside the loop or ?

UPDATE2

```
let c1 = document.getElementsByClassName("currency-one");
let c2 = document.getElementById("currency-two");
let amount1 = document.getElementsByClassName("amount-one");
const amount2 = document.getElementById("amount-two");
const swap = document.getElementById("swap");
const theRate = document.getElementById("rate");



function calculate(c1,amount1) {
    let curr1 = c1.innerHTML;
    const curr2 = c2.innerHTML;
    console.log(amount1.value,parseInt(amount1.value),amount1)
    const rate = parseInt(amount1.value)  / parseFloat(amount2.innerHTML);    
    theRate.innerText = `You can buy maximum  -> you wallet money ${parseInt(amount1.value) } ${curr1}  = ${rate} ${curr2}`;
  }      

for(var i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {

    c1[i].innerHTML.click = function (){
        console.log("11111")
        c1.textContent = this.innerHTML;
    }
    amount1[i].value.click = function (){
        console.log("22222")
        amount1.textContent = this.value;
    }
    c1[i].addEventListener("change", calculate);
    amount1[i].addEventListener("input", calculate);   
}

   



c2.addEventListener("change", calculate);
amount2.addEventListener("input", calculate);


swap.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const flash = c1.value;
  c1.value = c2.value;
  c2.value = flash;
  calculate();
});
```

Only this part of the code do something

```
    c1[i].addEventListener("change", calculate);
    amount1[i].addEventListener("input", calculate);
```

I receive a info in console log

```
undefined NaN HTMLCollection(3) [input.amount-one, input.amount-one, input.amount-one]
```

I still have no idea how to make this code functional,
I don't know how to get to these values in the for loop and use the selected one in the calculator function?

Answer (score 0):

the problem exists here:

```
c1.addEventListener("change", calculate);
amount1.addEventListener("input", calculate);
c2.addEventListener("change", calculate);
amount2.addEventListener("input", calculate);
```

you are trying to use the "addEventListener" context on "getElementsByClassName" and this getElementsByClassName refers to many of the elements since you put these elements in for loop so, this className will be reading as an array.

the solution is:

you should loop these classes which are p.currency-one and input.amount-one as it said in the console then you can apply your eventListener function after that

for example:

```
const c1 = document.getElementsByClassName("currency-one");
let target = document.getElementById("div-for-example")

for(var i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
    // Update
    c1[i].click = function () {
        target.textContent = this.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update

Now, no matter what I click the USD or the Japanese Yen I get the last currency from the for loop not the one I chose, how to fix it?

Comment: you can see my example test on the updated post, you should use this keyword in that case. note: I typed the fake "id" in the example but you should create something like that to execute your code

Comment: Still, nothing I also tryed to console.log(MYtargetTHING.textContent)
c1[i].click = function calculator() and also c1[i].click = function  
                                                                                                  
calculator(c1,amount1) JS is a total novelty for me. When c1 and amount1 is in for loop I cant use  addEventListener                                                                     ```
c1.addEventListener("change", calculate);
amount1.addEventListener("input", calculate);                                                     
```